# Codenameone NetworkManager hangs after few request

Tags: codenameone

I have been having this issue with the NetworkManager which hangs/stuck forever after few request repeatedly (Url with different parameter still).  Mostly it works till the 4th request then on the 5th request it hangs.

Please see the code

```
ConnectionRequest r = new ConnectionRequest();
r.setUrl(url);
r.setPost(false);
r.setDuplicateSupported(true);
NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueueAndWait(r);  // hangs right here     
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(r.getResponseData()), "UTF-8");
```

I have read few others had the same issue and I did add setDuplicateSupported(true) still getting the same error.

Any help is really appreciated.  I really thank for Shai (from codename one) for being very supportive.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

`addToQueueAndWait` literally waits until the network request finishes and in this case it doesn't finish or timeout. You can set a timeout to a lower value to make this fail more gracefully. I suggest reviewing the request you are making and why it is failing.

I also suggest looking at the network monitor to see what is going on.

Comment: Hi Shai, 
I did look at the network monitor, as it didn't show any error message instead I was seeing the response text.  Here is what i am doing.
I have a button and text box for the email in a dialog box.  When I click the button the event is getting fired and the method is called to pull the information passing the email.  addToQueueAndWait responds for the first 4 times then it hangs, but in the network monitor I do see the request every time I click and also see the response.

Comment: Do you do something in any of your callback methods like show a dialog or something? If you press pause in the debugger you should see where the threads are stuck.